# Vserv appwrapper gives Failed message

Tags: android, apk, ads

I have an android app that I am trying to ad-wrap using the Vserv.mobi appwrapper. Below are the steps that I follow:-

1. Select 'Wrap Android'
2. Add the .apk file
3. Set Show At = Both
4. Entered the Zone ID & ZoneID end
5. Set View Mandatory = Can view
6. Set Cache = Yes
7. Kept all fields in Label section blank
8. In Advanced section set Block Ads=No and Location Ads=Allowed all other fields are blank
9. Set Code Signing=Self
10. Add keystore file, set alias name, set alias store password & set key password
11. Set the output folder path
12. Click on 'Wrap App'

However I always seem to get the 'Failed (1 out of 1)' message.

Log file does not give too much information either:-

"APK folder location path !!!Failed!!!"

Does anyone know how to find the specific reasons due to which the wrapping failed?

Comment: Hi Sid, could you email me : ravi @ vserv.mobi, I will connect you to our support team.

Comment: Hi Ravi: I will do that but aside from the external communication, could we have a more detailed description of the error or exception in the log file? It would be more helpful to the developers for debugging the issue.